# How can I make sure a function only runs once with multiple bindings and events firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm working with [jQuery.payment](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment) on a credit card number text input field.  When the user enters any 4th number (4, 8, 12) the plugin automatically puts in a space for a nice look.  Because of this, only the `keyup` event fires, not the `input` event.  However, if the user were to right-click and paste a value in, then only the `input` event fires.  So we have cases where it's one or the other, or both events firing.

I have a bound anonymous function for `change keyup input` to ensure all use-cases are covered, but I want the function to only run once each time the key is pressed, but normal key presses fire both `keyup` and `input`.  jQuery's `.one()` is not an option because this function needs to run more than once, just not twice for one key press.  How can I make sure this function only runs once even when both events are fired from one key press?

I know I could edit jQuery.payment and trigger the `input` event, but I don't want to modify vendor plug-ins, in case I decide to change versions or something down the road.

Comment: This may be a good start => [https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput)

Comment: if you only listen to the `change` event it should work right? No need for keyup or input

Comment: `change` typically doesn't fire from normal key presses.  I'm just running a simple `console.log(e)` in the function to see events, and `change` doesn't pop up very often when typing, backspacing, or pasting.

Comment: @LShetty I just tried `.oninput` and it is suffering the same problem because of jQuery.payment.  The `input` event is not fired on the 4th numbers, so it doesn't run.

Comment: @Brandon did you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbedvLnf/)?

Comment: @LShetty No, not quite.  The problem with that is when only the `keyup` fires, then nothing will happen.  More like "if both `keyup` and `input` fire do this only once."  Which seems hard, because I believe this function is running twice, independently, so each one will not know the other is running.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no other option than to ensure that your anonymous event handler is *idempotent* (for a given state of the input) - ie, that the same state arises regardless of how many events trigger the handler.

Comment: @Brandon how about enabling `keyup` only when `input` is not available? This way, either input or keyup will fire.

Comment: @LShetty How can I tell if `input` is available or not?

Comment: @Brandon [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbedvLnf/1/)

Comment: @Brandon any luck on this?

Comment: @LShetty It's close, maybe?  The function is only running once when both events fire, however, it's not running at all when only `keyup` fires.  Here's an image of my console: http://imgur.com/fxO6Y3S

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sorry, I missed your comment earlier.  I'm a little lost here, how would I go about implementing your suggestion?

Comment: @Brandon my last [hacky version](http://jsfiddle.net/zbedvLnf/2/) before I head out to a pub. Let me know :)

Comment: @LShetty Same problem, `keyup` never runs the function, even on its own.  The `boundEvents` always contains `change`, `input`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`, `paste` despite the event type.  I'm also confused at what `'oninput' in document.createElement('input')` is doing here.  If we create an `input`, `oninput` is always `in` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play around with attaching/detaching event handlers all day and never hit on a successful formula.

If your event handler was [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (for a given input state), then you wouldn't need to worry about triggering it twice.

If the handler is not naturally idempotent, then you can include a condition which ensures that a second successive call, with the same input value, does nothing. It's slightly contrived, but this can be regarded as "forced idempotence".

To achieve this, the input element's "last state" (its value) needs to be stored, read back and tested.

You could store the state in some outer/global javascript var but it's neater to use a '.data()' property of the element itself (which is actually 100% js, not pushed into the DOM).

```
$(function() {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup input", function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $lastState = $this.data('lastState') || '',//read back the element's previous state (or empty string if this is the first call)
            val = $this.val();//current state
        if(val !== $lastState) {//the all-important test.
            $this.data('lastState', val);//store current state to be read back at next call
            //here do whatever is required of your event handler.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  I copied/pasted it, put my function call in place of your last comment, tested it, and it's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, cool! If you were going to have many such inputs on one page, then you could refactor the code as a jQuery plugin which emulates `.on()` but with that special condition applied.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 +1, real neat one :)

Answer (score -1):

I would use jQuery change event and always make sure the event was not binded before. And i would not follow a logic like "when user presses the 4th digit". Instead i would format the whole text every time.

```
function MyInputChanged(){
  var currentText = $("#myInput").val();
  var newText = someFunctionToFormatText(currentText);
  $("#myInput").val(newText);
}

$("#myInput").unbind("change", MyInputChanged);
$("#myInput").bind("change", MyInputChanged);
```

Comment: In this situation, that doesn't work, this is an issue created from using a plugin that I don't want to modify.  There are cases where only `keyup` fires or only `input` fires.  I need to bind both events, but the problem is when they both fire together - I don't want the function to run twice in that situation.  `change` doesn't fire from normal key presses.